# select all date that is lesser than today

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (`mytable`) that contains:

```
id, date
```

and some rows (the Id is for the example):

```
4235          null
3563   2013-11-27 08:02:53.917
3143   2013-11-27 01:04:51.917
1455          null
5223   2013-11-26 08:02:53.917
2123   2013-11-25 08:02:53.917
```

I want to select all the rows that their date before today or the date is null.

so in my example, if I run the query on `2013-11-27` I want to get:

```
4235          null
1455          null
5223   2013-11-26 08:02:53.917
2123   2013-11-25 08:02:53.917
```

I think to do it with:

```
select case when
(
(select DATEPART(yyyy,dailybudgetexceeded) from sensplit_commercial_goal where 
commercialGoalId = 'dbe20d71-e304-4989-8524-5feef61d32a7') >= YEAR(GETDATE()) 
or...
```

but maybe there is a shorter way.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean dates before *today*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * 
from sensplit_commercial_goal
where commercialGoalId = 'dbe20d71-e304-4989-8524-5feef61d32a7'
and (dailybudgetexceeded < getdate() or dailybudgetexceeded is null)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
select * from mytable
where [date] < Convert(date, getdate())  or [date] is null
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1ac2/2)

Comment: Why cast GetDate() to Date?

Comment: If the query is run on 2013-11-27 08:02:54.917, the record with 2013-11-27 08:02:53.917 will also be returned by the query, unless you cast GetDate() to Date

Comment: The OP didn't ask to truncate the time - at least not clearly

Comment: "I want to select all the rows that their date is lesser than now (the levels of day/month/year) or the date is null." Please also see the expected result set posted by the OP

Comment: Yes, you can *guess* that he means dates before today. If he confirms it, he should edit the post

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM sensplit_commercial_goal
WHERE dailybudgetexceeded  < CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) OR dailybudgetexceeded  IS NULL
```

Comment: Why cast GetDate() to Date?

Comment: To truncate the time part of the datetime.